# MPI_Waitall and non blocking receive invalid

Tags: c, parallel-processing, mpi

I get a 0xc0000005 error code waiting for all receives from rank != 0 processes. Im sending a blocking send from != 0 processes and want to receive them non blocking for each process in the for loop. I later wait for all receives with waitall but thats when I get an error.

```
if (rank == 0)
{
    grids* sudokuList;
    
    sudokuList = initParallel(process_count);

    int* data;
    data = (int*)malloc((process_count - 1) * sizeof(int));
    MPI_Request* recvRequests = (MPI_Request*)malloc((process_count - 1) * sizeof(MPI_Request));
    MPI_Request* sendRequests = (MPI_Request*)malloc((process_count - 1) * sizeof(MPI_Request));
    grids* ptr;
    ptr = sudokuList;

    for (int i = 1; i < process_count; i++)
    {
        MPI_Isend(ptr->grid.sudoku, N * N, MPI_INT, i, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &sendRequests[i - 1]);
        MPI_Irecv(data+i, 1, MPI_INT, i, 2, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &recvRequests[i - 1]);
        ptr = ptr->next;
    }
    if (ptr != NULL)
    {
        lookForSolution(ptr->grid, rank);
        ptr = ptr->next;
    }
    MPI_Status* sendStatuses = (MPI_Status*)malloc((process_count - 1) * sizeof(MPI_Status));
    MPI_Waitall(process_count - 1, sendRequests, sendStatuses);

    // CRITICAL CODE
    // 

    MPI_Status* statuses = (MPI_Status*)malloc((process_count - 1) * sizeof(MPI_Status));
    MPI_Waitall(process_count - 1, recvRequests, statuses);

    free(recvRequests);
    free(sendStatuses);
    free(sendRequests);
    free(data);
    delete_grids(sudokuList);

}
else
{
    lookForSolution(recvGrid(), rank);

    // CRITICAL CODE
    MPI_Send(1, 1, MPI_INT, 0, 2, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
}
```

Comment: In `MPI_Send(1, 1, MPI_INT, 0, 2, MPI_COMM_WORLD);` the first arg should be a buffer pointer but it is `1`. Compiling with warnings enabled (`-Wall`) should have flagged this.

Comment: I get a heap corruption error now. Apparently i write after a heap end.

Comment: You receive past the end of the "data" array

Comment: Per Gilles you want: `data = malloc(process_count * sizeof(int));`